# SendGrid category not being set

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid, swiftmailer

I'm redoing a project that has SendGrid integrated for mailing.

Well, I'm using Laravel and Mailable classes, and I have created a function to set the SendGrid category:

```
public function setSendgridCategory($category){
    $encodedCategory = json_encode(['category' => $category]);
    $this->withSwiftMessage(function (\Swift_Message $message) use ($encodedCategory){
        $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $encodedCategory);
    });
}
```

I have a listener which logs my headers, and they look like:

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 13:47:32 +0100
Subject: XXXXXXXXX.
From: xXXXXXx <system@xxXXxXXXXXX.com>
To: XXXXxxx <XxXXX@xxXXXxXXX.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-SMTPAPI: {"category":"Otros"}
```

Also tried with an array

X-SMTPAPI:  {"category":["Otros"]}

The name of the category is exactly the same as the one that is already being tracked on SendGrid, but when I look on the SendGrid activity log, the email is sent, but no category is set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sendgrid configurations are correctly set under your mail driver, correct? Mails are sending, only issue is with the category, yes?

Comment: Yep, the emails are being sent, and the html is perfectly parsed, just the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after testing everything that came to my mind, and messing with the encodings as @bwest suggested, changing the driver on my .env file solved it.

I don't know where did I get it from, but I had my driver set as

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendgrid
```

and it was sending mails correctly, so I didn't pay attention to it, I changed it to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

and now my categories are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Category needs to be an array. Try: `{"category":["Otros"]}`

Comment: hmmm... what charset and encoding is the string that you are passing to `setSendgridCategory`? Categories have to be in 7-bit/US-ASCII. Try to force the encoding and charset perhaps.

Comment: The string is in ASCII, I tried to modify the header Content-Transfer-Encoding to 7-bit/US-ASCII but keep without luck